# Use Babel with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to write my first babel program and kind of stuck.

#### I wrote script 1

```
var message = "Hello World";
module.exports = message;
```

#### and script2

```
var message = require('./script1');
document.write(`This is formatted with ES6 ${message}`);
```

#### my webpack.config.js looks like

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
         main: [
            './script1.js',
            './script2.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "./public/[name].js"
    },
    loaders: {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
    }
}
```

The above code works and I am able to see the output but now if I modify script2 to

```
import message from './script1';
document.write(`This is formatted with ES6 ${message}`);
```

then when I run webpack it says

```
ERROR in ./script2.js
Module parse failed: /Users/a.c/MyProjects/ReactTutorial/script2.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import message from './script1';
| document.write(`This is formatted with ES6 ${message}`);
 @ multi main
```

My understanding is that because I am using babel, I should be able to use the new ES6 way of importing stuff into my code easily.

Comment: protip: never use `document.write`. Use something like `console.log` if you just want to know that things work. `document.write` is an ancient low level JS function with highly destructive power. Don't use it unless you absolutely *know* you need to. Not even for throw-away test. Just use console logs, same amount of typing, infinitely better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have forgotten to specify [`es2015 preset`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) for babel.

1. Make sure it's installed:

   ```
   > npm i -D babel-preset-es2015
   ```
2. You have two options to specify this preset for babel.

   1. Create `.babelrc` file and specify the preset there:

      ```
      {
          "presets": ["es2015"]
      }
      ```
   2. Specify the preset using [`query` property](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#query):

      ```
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: /src/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
              presets: ['es2015']
            }
          }
        ]
      }
      ```

Answer (score 4):

Try add `resolve.extensions` to config file (in order to avoid always write extensions when you import `.js` or `.jsx` files) also if you are using `babel 6` you need install couple packages [`babel-preset-es2015`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) and [`babel-preset-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react)

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
         main: [
            './script1.js',
            './script2.js'
        ]
    },

    output: {
        filename: "./public/[name].js"
    },

    loaders: {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, // or /\.(js|jsx)$/
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
 }
```